# how to remove attributes from a Mongoid Model, i.e., not just nullifying their values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I was experimenting the polymorphic associaton in Mongoid

```
class Group
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :groupable, polymorphic: true
end

class Album
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :groups, as: groupable
end
```

then I decided against it. So I removed all those belongs_to and has_many lines above. Yet in the console, whenever I get a Group record that I experimented with, it still has this "groupable_type" attribute. I know remove_attribute nullify the attribute, but does not remove it( sounds a bit like JavaScript). How can I actually remove this attribute from the database from Mongoid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Group.collection.update({},
                        {'$unset' => {:groupable_type => 1}},
                        :multi => true)
```

Comment: I did see something about "unset" after googling, didn't realize it is something from the mongo console. -- in your opinion, isn't this a bit cumbersome to remove a field? thanks!

Comment: It's not "from mongo console", it's a first-class mongodb operator. Mongoid might have a helper method for this, but there's nothing bad in going to underlying driver. Also, you can always write such helper yourself. :)

Comment: oops.. ooops.. ooops.. whenever I saw the $ thing, some reason, I thought of the console.. Sorry about that. And I couldn't agree more, having such underlying POWERFUL first-class operators was one big reason why I migrated to MongoDB/Mongoid (and also so that I don't have to "migrate" anything anymore :D ). Waiting another 3 minutes to check "answered"

Comment: `MongoidCollection.all.unset(:attribute_name)` is much simpler and cleaner way.

Comment: @konflikt, I believe you should place this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As of version 5.0.0 of Mongoid, the gem has switched from using Moped to use the 'official ruby MongoDB driver' which has a different syntax for updates. Reference: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/

The documentation for collection methods is here:
http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html

There are 2 methods, "update" and "update_many". You can use update_many instead of specifying the 'multi' option to update all documents.

Example use for the OPs case:

```
Group.collection.update_many({}, {'$unset' => {'groupable_type' => true}})
```

Note you can unset embedded documents using dot notation:

```
Group.collection.update_many({}, {'$unset' => {'embedded_doc.groupable_type' => true}})
```

Note it is not well supported by MongoDB to unset / update fields within an array. See this thread for info and workarounds: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243.

Answer (score 1):

For a single instance, it is possible (at least in recent versions of Mongoid) to use directly `unset` on your instance

```
Group.first.unset('groupable_type')
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in Moped 2.0.0.rc1 the update method is gone on collection, but this works;

```
Group.collection.find().update(
                    {'$unset' => {:groupable_type => 1}},
                    :multi => true)
```